# Parsing double to DoubleWritable of Hadoop MapReduce in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reducers

Hi I am new to Hadoop I am stuck at a point where I do not have any clue what am I doing wrong. I am trying to parse simple double value into DoubleWritable of hadoop but it is giving me 0.0.

```
0.0 Southwest 
0.0 US Airways 
0.0 United 
0.0 Virgin America
```

Below is what I am trying to do:

```
double negativeWords = 0;
for(DoubleWritable value : values) {        
    if(value.get() < 0) {
        negativeWords = negativeWords + 1;
    }
}
logger.info("NEGATIVE WORDS: " +negativeWords + " KEY: " + key);
context.write(key, new DoubleWritable(negativeWords));
```

Mapper class is

```
public class USAirlineComparisionMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(USAirlineComparisionMapper.class);
    private final static DoubleWritable tempResult = new DoubleWritable();
    private Text tempAirline = new Text();
    private Set<String> negativeSet;
    private Set<String> positiveSet;

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        negativeSet = new HashSet<String>();
        positiveSet = new HashSet<String>();

        for(String negWord : conf.get("negativewords").split(",")) {
            negativeSet.add(negWord);
        }
        for(String posWord : conf.get("positivewords").split(",")) {
            positiveSet.add(posWord);
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        double positiveWords = 0;
        double negativeWords = 0;
        double otherWords = 0;
        double result = 0;

        try {
        String[] row = value.toString().split(",");
        String tweet = row[10];
        tempAirline.set(row[5]);

        String[] splitedTweet = tweet.split(" ");

        for(int i = 0; i < splitedTweet.length; i++) {      

            if(splitedTweet[i] != " ") {
                if(negativeSet.contains(splitedTweet[i].trim().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ""))) {
                    negativeWords++;
                }else if(positiveSet.contains(splitedTweet[i].trim().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ""))) {
                    positiveWords++;
                }else {
                    otherWords++;
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            result = (positiveWords - negativeWords)/(positiveWords + negativeWords + otherWords);

            logger.info("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
            logger.info("RESULT: " +result );
            logger.info("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");

        }catch(ArithmeticException e) {
            result = 1;
        }

        tempResult.set(Math.round(result * 100.0) /100.0);
        /*logger.info("==============================================");
        logger.info("result : " + result);
        logger.info("==============================================");*/
        context.write(tempAirline, tempResult);

    }catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error(" ", e);
    }
    }
}
```

Most interesting part is in my log I am getting the desired output that is:

> NEGATIVE WORDS: 345.0 KEY: Delta  NEGATIVE WORDS: 293.0 KEY: Southwest
>   NEGATIVE WORDS: 19.0 KEY: US Airways  NEGATIVE WORDS: 650.0 KEY: United
>   NEGATIVE WORDS: 87.0 KEY: Virgin America

Comment: output should be like : **delta 345 southwest 293 and so on** but i am getting **delta 0.0 southwest 0.0 and so on**

Comment: Delta 0.0
Southwest 0.0
US Airways 0.0
United 0.0
Virgin America 0.0
thats what i am getting :|

Comment: Please add your mapper code and input file

Comment: @cricket_007 how can i upload the input file here? btw i have updated my question. Now you can check mapper